# Edit a Jlable by using a variable to call it?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jlabel

I am writing some code and I want to make it as flexible as possible, so I'm using a lot of variables and I have a string variable called `username`. I also have some Jlabels that have the same names as anything that could possibly go into the `username` variable. How can I change the enabled state of the Jlabel that corresponds to the string in the `username` variable?

EDIT: For some clarification, I have a hashmap that contains keys for the ID's that I want to accept from the user. Those keys point to objects with `name` (string) and `status`(boolean) variables. For each entry into the hashmap I am going to add a Jlabel that holds the photo of that person. The Jlabels name will correspond to the `name` in the objects.

EDIT: So first it checks the hashmap to see if the entered number matches one of the keys in the hashmap. If it does it copies `name` from that object to `username` then checks the status of the object. If `status` is false (default) I want it to change the Jlabel with the same name as `username` to enabled. Change to disable if `status` is true. Remember I will have to scale this up later with lots of objects and Jlabels.

My issue is I can't tell java which Jlabel to change without useing a ton of IF statements.

I was thinking something like this but it will return a compiler error: "The method setEnabled (boolean) is undefined for the type String"

```
username.setEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you are using a `HashMap<String, boolean>` but you really should be using a `HashMap<String, JLabel>` because you can use the `isEnabled()` and `setEnabled(boolean b)` directly on the `JLabels` attached to their `String` IDs. Demonstrated by this code snippet from the below example:

```
HashMap<String, JLabel> yourMap = new HashMap<>();
// ...
yourMap.get(id).setEnabled(!yourMap.get(id).isEnabled());
```

Enter `12345` or `54321` into the `JTextField` and press enter to toggle if the two `JLabel`s are enabled or not:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                final JFrame frame = new JFrame("JLabel Text Example");

                final HashMap<String, JLabel> yourMap = new HashMap<>();
                yourMap.put("12345", new JLabel("Example Text"));
                yourMap.put("54321", new JLabel("Other Text"));

                final JTextField input = new JTextField(5);
                input.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        String text = input.getText();
                        if(yourMap.get(text) != null) {
                            yourMap.get(text).setEnabled(!yourMap.get(text).isEnabled());
                        }
                    }

                });

                final JPanel labels = new JPanel();
                labels.setLayout(new BoxLayout(labels, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
                for(JLabel label : yourMap.values()) {
                    labels.add(label);
                }

                frame.getContentPane().add(input);
                frame.getContentPane().add(labels, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }

}
```

Comment: This isn't a bad solution if im using only 1 JLabel but I need to have 1 Jlabel for each object in my hash map. I probably should have explained a little better, so the user enters an ID number into a text box, it converts the string to an integer then checks to see if that integer matches any keys in my hash map that i have. If it does it then checks the state variable I made for the object that corresponds to that key. If the state is false (default) i want to set it to true and visa versa. Each object will be paired with a Jlabel that contains there picture. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, but this should be an edit to your question.

Comment: I want to tell java which Jlabel to edit depending on what is in the `username` variable

Comment: oh yea der ill change it

Comment: Ok I think I got it working. I made a couple tweaks to your code, instead of having a status variable like i did before i just check if the JLabel is enabled then take the same action I would have with the variable. And now that were not using the objects I set the name of the JLabel later and get the username from that! Thanks for your help!